# Firefox Bug: Footer wrapping around main content

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

Hello I have a bug that has been haunting me for the past few days.

we have this redesign we're working on for www.petpoint.com -

http://test.petpoint.com/redesign/index.asp

If viewed in any other browser the footer looks fine (even in IE7, 8)

When viewed in firefox the footer gets real messed up.

I cannot figure out this bug, I have tried to see if its something in the CSS but nothing i've tried as made that footer budge.

I could use any help you can lend.  Not sure if you can get to the link so I can provide code samples on request.

[image: As seen in firefox]

[image: as seen everywhere else]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks the same on all browsers. An image would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah looks fine on my end maybe your zoomed in, in firefox. An image would be useful

Comment: because I don't have 10 points I can't post images.  Firefox version I have is 3.6.17, its been confirmed on another computer with firefox.

Comment: See my answer below - also change your doc type to this - <!DOCTYPE html> since your using HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missing `<` leaving an unclosed `</b>` in this line:

`<b>24PetWatch microchips sold for companion animal usage/b>`

I think that's compounding  down.. it's hard to debug because from that point on FireBug shows that FF is inserting `<b></b>` DOM elements/tags in weird places - sometimes wrapping your existing elements, sometimes, not for the rest of the source, which is subsequently breaking the footer.

I see these `<b>` elements are not actually in your source code so it's possible this one error is the cause, if not give a shout back

even if the HTML5 tags won't validate, a good check for other wrongly nested elements is the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), though I've never seen FF do something quite this severe with non closed inline elements!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to close a couple of tags.  [Validate your Markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://test.petpoint.com/redesign/index.asp)

I would also suggest you to use `<strong></strong>` instead of `<b></b>` 
Another thing I noticed don't wrap your `.li` with `<b></b>` try to apply the `font-weight:bold` property to your list. Its cleaner and standard.

Comment: sigh, the issue was an unclosed <b> / <strong> tag. FML I wasted hours going through CSS and jquery stuff.

Thanks alot guys.  I'm glad its fixed.

Comment: No problem. Would have been nice to have gotten the answer though. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some code messed up between the  tags and the content within the first column is not being written within the  tags. This appears to be the case for all of the columns. It also looks like you may be trying to add some CSS `moz` styles that are being inserted and messing up the code. In Chrome the  header tags in the footer do not have  tags within them, but in FF they do.

Hope this helps. Keep us updated on anything else you find.